# Fade out previous node upon fading in new one in reveal.js

Tags: slideshow, reveal.js

I am trying to build elegant "fill in the blank" exercises for my students in presentations shown through reveal.js.

```
<p class="fragment">
Birds are able to fly because they possess
<span class="fragment">wings</span>
.</p>
```

This works great, but as we go through the slide, I would like previous sentences to *fade out*. If you add the fade-in-then-out class to the p element, then the nested span element will appear for a brief fraction of a second before the whole sentence vanishes. Such is the behavior to be expected of course : as we move from the p fragment to the span fragment, p, which encompasses span, disappears.

How could I make this sentence fade out when the next one fades in ? How would you go about achieving that ? Through an event listener maybe ?

Thanks for your help !

---

### Addition

Upon switching from one fragment to the other, all the fragments on the slide get back to their original : thus it looks futile to remove the "visible" class via the reveal.on 'fragmentshown' listener. At least it didn't work for me.